# Should we just allow open source?

Tags: discussion, scope

In the question [Are NC Creative Commons licenses on topic?](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/are-nc-creative-commons-licenses-on-topic) I argued that the NC-clause of Creative Commons (and ND for that matter) isn't conforming to Open Source (while CC-BY and CC-SA are). But in the [commentaries](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76/are-nc-creative-commons-licenses-on-topic/83?noredirect=1#comment194_83) we discussed the point, if the site might include it anyways. So, should stuff beyond Open Source (but connected through communities, ideas and ideals or something else) be allowed? And if we do, what is the focus of opensource.SE?

EDIT: An example besides licensing: [What exactly is a pull request?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/352/what-exactly-is-a-pull-request). Directly it is unrelated to open source, as even proprietary projects can have pull request. But in reality it is connected to an open development model, usually connected with open source. It is a good question, and I wouldn't mind if it is on-topic, but we have to define if it is or not.

Answer (score 9):

Having commented, I might as well put up my thoughts:

Here's the Area 51 "Blurb"

> Beta Q&A site for people organizing, marketing or licensing open source development projects.

I think the first thing to realize is that this site isn't just about licensing open source projects, but organizing and marketing them as well. I feel as if this is become a licensing site. [We're also seeming to include Free Software details...](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/a/101/69)

That being said, I feel like that isn't enough. An additional focus that I would like to see (and I perfectly understand if there is disagreement) is more inclusion for non-software related stuff. Other stuff and stuff. Creative Commons would be a good fit for that.

All this together, I feel unclear as to what our main focus has evolved to, as well as what the side of fries is. I think we should look more, and if people have proposals to add to the site, that they ***please*** bring it up here in Meta. :)

Answer (score 7):

**I believe we should judge whether questions are on topic here, not exclude questions that happen to be on topic elsewhere.**

So questions that are relevant to people using, working with or working on open source projects should be on topic, and if these questions happen to also help other people who are not connected with open source, that does not detract from their usefulness and relevance.

---

Obviously there must be some link to open source. Not every problem that people working on open source come up against is on topic here. Many people who work on open source projects order take away food, but asking about that wouldn't fit here. So this is a rough guide not a definitive rule.

Comment: I like this answer. It defines sort of a focus, while not having the focus extremely limited.