# Are questions about Open Data and Open Standards on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I found [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site which follows [Open Definition](http://opendefinition.org/).  So, I would like to ask whether it is on-topic here or not? In other words, Is there a case that questions on this site should be migrated to [Open Data](http://opendata.stackexchange.com)? Or guide/suggestion to user to choose between.

Another question is for [Open Standards and it's requirements](http://opensource.org/osr). Are they a fit (on-topic) for this site?

Answer (score 4):

Questions about the history, philosophies and licenses of Open Data and Open Standards are on-topic.

Questions asking for recommendations, using some data/standard, explanations of the Standards, tools for manipulating data etc are off-topic.

Comment: This, to me, is the right answer. We should be primarily concerned with our own site. If we can answer a question that is asked here, we should do so. If Open Data would really provide way better answers, tell the OP.

Comment: I agree with some of what you have to say, however, I think that explanations should be on+topic, otherwise, people wonæt have the chance to determine what open data is, and what is considered open, clauses of openness and so on. Otherwise, this looks good.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've typed from a Norwegian keyboard... Just substitute the æ for '

Answer (score 2):

Open Data is very tricky. We have a site for that, but their [help center](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) doesn't seem crystal clear to me:

> If you have a question about …
>
> - where to find any kind of open data
> - software tools related to open data
> - best practices regarding open data
> - licensing and releasing open data
> - open data formats and standards
> - linked data, ontologies and related semantic technologies
> - analysis and visualization of open data

Open Data has its own site, let them be. On the other hand, it seems that we are accepting questions about Open Knowledge ([read more here](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/881/what-is-open-knowledge-and-how-is-it-different-from-open-data)), as per [this meta post](https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212/should-questions-pertaining-to-open-knowledge-be-in-scope). It will be tricky deciding what to put, but I feel that there are similarities, and we need to be specific with what we allow. Leave that for another meta post.

---

The Open Standard is very similar to the Open Definition. The Open Standard was created by Open Source. Therefore, it should clearly be on-topic as it's highly related to FLOSS. That being said, I feel that questions pertaining to the Open Definition should be on topic as well.

Comment: Topics can be on-topic on multiple sites. In this case there'll be a partial overlap of what we'll allow for Open Data.

Comment: what about the help center isn't crystal clear? specifically? i'd like to get that amended