Are questions about licenses that ban commercial use on-topic or off-topic?
Examples of licenses that ban commercial use:

https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/4.0/deed.en
https://github.com/adobe-research/VideoDoodles/blob/main/LICENSE.md

Are questions about licenses that ban commercial use on-topic or off-topic?

Does this answer your question? Are Source Visible Questions On Topic?

Consensus renewed here in 2020

[ I guess the above assumes you are aware that licenses that ban commercial use are not open source ]

@PhilipKendall Thank you I was confused because I saw many questions on CC BY-NC*.  https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com/a/777/210 states "one exception has been the non-Free CC licenses, because they form such a clearly defined family with the free CC licences, so some CC BY-ND or CC BY-NC questions are allowed.". This clears up my confusion.

Nearly everything that needs to be said has been said in comments, but I suppose this should have an actual answer drawing it all together.
First and foremost, we currently have a canonical question on the subject, and it's clear that the freedom to commercially exploit software is guaranteed by both the OSI's open source definition, and the FSF's four freedoms.  So questions specifically about how to remove this freedom are therefore questions about non-free restrictions, and current consensus appears to be that we don't, generally, do those.
This consensus was last renewed in 2020.  That doesn't mean it's permanent, but if you'd like to advocate for a change, it'd be helpful to read all the old discussions first, to see if you can bring something new to the table.  Simply retreading old paths isn't an immensely productive use of anyone's time, and the community may not be interested in participating.
That said, not all questions that merely involve a non-commercial licence would strike me as off-topic.  One that asked how to remove such a restriction, for example, would seem acceptable to me, as would one about compatibility between code licensed non-commercially and code licensed permissively-freely.  But repeats of the hoary old chestnut "how do I stop people making money off my free software?" are probably going to get closed quite promptly.
